# View cart success message

Tags: wordpress

I have used this method "woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart()" in my plugin and it's working fine. now i want to display the view cart success message on the same template, for now it's showing on the cart page. Can anyone help that how to go for this? thanks in advance.